# Docusaurus categories in sidebars.json don't show correctly

Tags: docusaurus

I have mutiple (more than 2) categories in the sidebars.json，it only render the first and the last one in the page，I can't find how to fix online. thanks.

Here is a producible repo: https://github.com/nianiaJR/doc-demo

Here is my sidebars.json: https://github.com/nianiaJR/doc-demo/blob/master/website/sidebars.json

I expect all navs config in the sidebars.json show in the page. But only the first and the last one show.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "type": "subcategory",
  "label": "Quick Start",
  "ids": [
    "doc1",
    "doc2",
    "doc3"
  ]
},
{
  "type": "subcategory",
  "label": "design-and-architecture",
  "ids": [
    "doc1",
    "doc2",
    "doc3"
  ]
}
```

You have duplicates ids in a different category. You should not do that. The docs is confused whether 'doc1' belong to quick start or design and architecture

https://github.com/nianiaJR/doc-demo/blob/6323eb2207b63cb53918e677681593a9cda9a08d/website/sidebars.json#L13-L29

Comment: Ok, I've delete remove the duplicate items. But the problem seems  still existed.

Comment: Oh, sorry I've found out what my problem. It's exactly like what your said, I've used the duplicates ids in my sidebars.json config.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a file named docker-compose.md with an id=docker-compose.  My .dockerignore file contained an entry **/docker-compose.

In this case changing the entry to **/docker-compose*.yml fixed the issue.